# Delete based on unique combination from 2nd table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an invoice header(Invoice) table and and invoice detail (invdet) table.  Invoice have inv_co and inv_no and invdet has invd_inv_co and invd_inv_no such as:

```
invoice table       invdet table
-----------------   ---------------------------------------
inv_co | inv_no     invd_inv_co | invd_inv_no | invd_seq_no
C01    | 129324     C01         | 129324      | 1
                    C01         | 129324      | 2
                    C01         | 129324      | 3
                    C01         | 129324      | 4
                    C01         | 129324      | 5
                    C03         | 129325      | 1
                    C03         | 129325      | 2
                    C03         | 129325      | 3
                    C03         | 129325      | 4
```

So I need to select the rows in invdet based on the unique combination of inv_co and inv_no in the invoice header table (Basically for a specified inv_co and inv_no I also want the corresponding detail rows).

I need to do a delete on the invdet table and currently I'm using a cursor and selecting the inv_co and inv_no from the cursor and doing a delete based off that but I am hoping someone knows a way I can do a delete in one query.

Hope I explained that well enough and thanks in advance!

Kevin

Comment: you can use joins and where in a delete statement if that's what you're trying to do..   `Delete t1 From Table1 t1 Join Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id`.. this would only delete the records from Table1 that exist in Table2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove `[ C01 | 129324 ]` from the `invdet` table but not from `invoice` table, you don't need to use a cursor, because you can just do:

```
DELETE FROM invdet WHERE invd_inv_co = 'C01' AND invd_inv_no = 129324
```

If you want to delete all records in `invdet` that have a matching record in `invoice`:

```
DELETE invdet
  FROM invdet INNER JOIN invoice
  ON (invd_inv_co = inv_co AND invd_inv_no = inv_no)
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make it clear in my question.  There are many rows not just the one.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri thanks for pointing this out. No it will not because it's only valid in MySQL, not in T-SQL as seems to be requested here.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri removed it from the answer because probably the OP was looking for the latter. But we'll never know... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the records from table `invdet` where values from columns `inv_co` and `inv_no` exists in table `invoice`, simply use the below query.

```
DELETE inv
FROM invdet inv
WHERE exists 
    (
        SELECT
            * 
        FROM invoice i 
        WHERE i.inv_co = inv.invd_inv_co 
            AND i.inv_no = invd_inv_no
    )
```

Hope this helps!